# How does one create a smaller overlay activity in android eclipse

Tags: java, android

i have successfully created an overlay activity which allows touch input to be sent to the window behind it. Everything works, however, it significantly slows down the device, my guessing is because its creating such a large overlay? I really dont need the overlay to be across the entire area of the screen, it technically could be as big as 2 x 2 pixels.

Here is my code

```
inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext());
final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new  WindowManager.LayoutParams(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

    params.flags |= WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE;
    params.flags |= WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL;
    params.flags |= WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN;
    //params.flags |= WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE;


    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
    ViewGroup mTopView = (ViewGroup)inflater.inflate(R.layout.dummy, null);
    getWindow().setAttributes(params);
    mTopView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE);
    wm.addView(mTopView, params);
```

This dos exactly what i want it to do, but like i said, it noticeably slows down the device. How can i create the overlay but yet retain system performance?

Comment: I also would like to be able to use `params.flags |= WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE` but that prevents `View.SYSTEM_UI_LOW_PROFILE` from taking effect. But without that, unless if i am doing something wrong, it also prevents the apps drawer from being executed from the home screen.

Comment: slow down the device or the emulator device?

Comment: The actual device. Was debugging using my Asus TF300T tablet. I must be doing something wrong because other "overlay" apps dont slow it down as much.

Comment: how come i got a notification that someone answered this but yet i see nothing?

Comment: oh duh. i thought of that :P lol. Wonder why they deleted it? From my notification it looked to be a snippet of some code.

Anyone have any ideas why this lags my device? Am i doing something wrong?